iOS Subscription Receipts Not Working in App Store Distribution
[I am a first-time poster...so I beg your forbearance if I'm doing this incorrectly.  If I need to do something differently, please let me know.]
I developed a mobile app for iOS and Android using .net Maui (JetBrains Rider IDE).  I created two subscription products in the App Store and integrated them into the app.  The app tests OK using debug builds locally on a connected iPhone but is failing in TestFlight and Distribution.  In the latter cases, I can see from the Lambda Clooudwatch logs that the function is not being called.
I know that AWS services can be reached in TestFlight because, before the subscription check, AWS Cognito is called successfully for authentication.  I can't tell if the Lambda Function is blocked because of the destination or because of the way it's called.
Here's how I'm calling the function in the .net Maui code:
[C#]
var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { receipt = receiptData });
                Debug.WriteLine($"Payload length: {payload.Length}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"Payload (first 100 chars): {payload.Substring(0, Math.Min(100, payload.Length))}");
                //Debug.WriteLine($"Payload: {payload}");
                var request = new InvokeRequest
                {
                    FunctionName = "[MY_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME]",
                    Payload = payload
                };

                Debug.WriteLine("Invoking Lambda function...");
                var response = await client.InvokeAsync(request);
                Debug.WriteLine($"Lambda function response received. StatusCode: {response.StatusCode}");

Here's the Python script I'm using for the Lambda Function:
[Python 3.12]
import json
import boto3
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import logging

# Environment variables for shared secret and other configuration
SHARED_SECRET = 'MY_SHARED_SECRET'  

# Configure logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def try_validation(url, payload):
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, json=payload, timeout=30)
        response.raise_for_status()
        logger.info(f"Request to {url} succeeded: {response.json()}")
        return response.json()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        logger.error(f"Request to {url} failed: {str(e)}")
        return {'status': 'RequestFailed', 'error': str(e)}

def validate_receipt_with_apple(receipt_data):
    payload = {
        'receipt-data': receipt_data,
        'password': SHARED_SECRET,
        'exclude-old-transactions': True
    }
    
    production_url = 'https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt'
    sandbox_url = 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt'
    
    # Try production first
    production_response = try_validation(production_url, payload)
    
    # If production returns 21007, try sandbox
    if production_response.get('status') == 21007:
        return try_validation(sandbox_url, payload)
    
    # For any other response, return the production response
    return production_response

def determine_subscription_status(receipt_info):
    current_time = int(datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000)  # Current time in milliseconds
    for purchase in receipt_info:
        expires_date_ms = int(purchase['expires_date_ms'])
        if expires_date_ms > current_time:
            return 'Active'
    return 'Expired'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info(f"Received event: {json.dumps(event)}")
    try:
        receipt = event.get('receipt')
        if not receipt:
            response_body = {'isValid': False, 'message': 'Receipt data is required'}
            logger.info(f"Response: {json.dumps(response_body)}")
            return {
                'statusCode': 400,
                'body': json.dumps(response_body)
            }
        
        validation_response = validate_receipt_with_apple(receipt)
        
        if validation_response.get('status') == 0:
            latest_receipt_info = validation_response.get('latest_receipt_info', [])
            subscription_status = determine_subscription_status(latest_receipt_info)
            latest_expiration = latest_receipt_info[-1].get('expires_date') if latest_receipt_info else None
            
            response_body = {
                'isValid': True,
                'subscriptionStatus': subscription_status,
                'environment': 'Production' if validation_response.get('environment') != 'Sandbox' else 'Sandbox',
                'latestExpirationDate': latest_expiration
            }
        else:
            response_body = {
                'isValid': False,
                'message': 'Receipt validation failed',
                'status': validation_response.get('status')
            }
        
        logger.info(f"Response: {json.dumps(response_body)}")
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(response_body)
        }
        
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in lambda_handler: {str(e)}")
        response_body = {'isValid': False, 'message': f'Server error during receipt validation: {str(e)}'}
        logger.info(f"Response: {json.dumps(response_body)}")
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps(response_body)
        }

I thank you all in advance for any assistance you can offer!

If your lambda function is not getting called in distribution, I would examine the part of the code that calls that. Do you have a build configuration that is different (i.e. debug/release) that calls different urls?

Taking guidance from Apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store), I call a Lambda Function from the mobile device.  The endpoints in the Lambda Python script are https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verify (production) and https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt (Sandbox).  Apple requires that you call them in that order, switching from production to Sandbox if a code 21003 response is received from the production server.  As such, there are no URLs in the app builds.

If I understand correctly, this IS getting called in the Maui app: var response = await client.InvokeAsync(request);. You can also verify that this method is getting called in TestFlight? Then this method: def lambda_handler(event, context): only gets called when debugging and never from the TestFlight version?

Thank you very much, tval, for your thoughtful responses!
I'm not aware of anything in the CSPROJ or other app configuration files that replaces the back-end calls in the release build.  I need to capture the traffic between the test mobile device running the release build and the back-end services to determine that authoritatively.
Focusing on the Lambda Function, I found that my original Python script was using decremented endpoints...and that the new Apple implementation of receipt validation requires JWT tokens (discussed here:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/simplifying_your_implementation_by_using_the_app_store_server_library).  In the Apple testing protocol, they still require trying the production endpoint first, and switching to the SandBox endpoint when a code 21003 response is generated.
Initially, I tried to modify the Lambda Function to use JWT tokens and the new endpoint.  There's a Python library for the app store server (https://github.com/apple/app-store-server-library-python) and a JWT token-generating library (jwt 1.3.1 - https://pypi.org/project/jwt/).  I tried using them in a Lambda layer but could not get it to work.
Instead, I set up a Node.js server which has also had challenges.  It uses the jsonwebtoken library  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) which has been yielding some unexpected results.  On investigation, I found that the JWT datestamp from generated tokens is January 1, 1970 which, of course, results in a failed call to the Apple servers.  I'm trying to address that now.  I just noticed a 'noTimestamp' option in jsonwebtoken that might solve my problem.
If anyone has had luck using jwt 1.3.1 in a Python Lambda Layer, I'd be grateful on any pointers you might have.  Otherwise, I'm leaning in on the Node.js implementation using jsonwebtoken.
